# Riemann Sum Help

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=1-x^2$.

A) Compute the left hand Riemann sum approximation of $\int_0^3 f(x)dx$ with $n=3$ boxes.

B) Compute the right hand Riemann sum approximation of $\int_0^3 f(x)dx$ with $n=3$ boxes.

C) Express $\int_0^3 f(x) dx$ as a limit of right hand Riemann sums (as in the definition integral). DO NOT EVALUATE THE LIMIT.

For part A) I got $0$, $1$, $2$ for the left points which gave me an area of $8$.

For part B) I got $1$, $2$, $3$ for the right points which gave me an area of $17$.

How would I do part C?

Comment: @BrianMScott Help please?

Comment: ^that's not the way things work. Also, you should limit your "question" to one *question*. Part C would suffice by itself. What have you tried for part C?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, its a sample midterm question from a previous year and it gives me the limits from 0 to 3

Comment: On my worksheet is explains that using the definitions from the first two parts, for part C, the integral from 0 to 3 if f(x) = lim from n-->infinity, n sum i=1 of (3 f(Xi)/n), where does the 3 in (3 f(Xi)/n) come from?? @TheChaz2.0

Answer (score 4):

Given:

$$\int_0^3 (1-x^2) ~dx$$

Find the integral using the left and right hand Riemann Sums with $n = 3$.

**Part A**

For the left RS, we have: $h = \dfrac{b-a}{n} = \dfrac{3-0}{3} = 1$

$$L = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(a + i h)h = \sum_{i=0}^2 (1 - i^2) = 1 + 0 - 3 = -2$$

**Part B**

For the right RS, we have: $h = \dfrac{b-a}{n} = \dfrac{3-0}{3} = 1$

$$R = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(a + (i+1)h)h = \sum_{i=0}^2 (1 - (i+1)^2) = 0 - 3 - 8 = -11$$

**Part C**

Can you figure this out?

Note: The actual result for the integral is $-6$, so the results above are horrible, but that is due to the number of points. If we use $100$ rectangles, we get much better results.

Comment: I thought the area couldn't be a negative? @Amzoti

Comment: We have as the integral = $x - \dfrac{x^3}{3}$. What do you get when you put the limits of integration in from $0$ to $3$? Also, did you plot the function to see why this result is valid?

Comment: @JXXII That's right, areas are non-negative. Integrals give signed area though.

Comment: @JXXII: Did you converge?

Comment: Part D: +1 $\checkmark.$

Comment: Indeed I am. Hope yours has been grand!

Comment: $++++++{}{}{}{}{}{}$